# elasticsearch nest client (5.x) : UpdateByQuery does not work

Tags: nest

I am using ES Nest Client 5.x (legacy project) and need to patch my documents.

My UpdateByQuery simply does not work; query never fetches anything to run the script against. There are no errors though.

```
 foreach (var index in indices)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Patching index{index} ...");

                    var result = client.UpdateByQuery<object>(
                        u => u
                            .Index(index)
                            .Query(
                                q => q.Match(w => w.Field("eventType").Query("ParameterAlarmOutOfRange"))
                            ).Script(
                                s => s.Inline("ctx._source.parameterName = ctx._source.action.splitOnToken(':')[0]").Lang("painless"))
                            .ErrorTrace(true)
                            .Conflicts(Conflicts.Abort)
                            .Refresh()
                    );

                }
```

this is the document:

```
{
        "_index" : "audit-trail-2023-02",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "qz3lc4YBSEcJ7Csqsrjt",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {        
          "eventType" : "ParameterAlarmOutOfRange",
          "parameterName" : "Temperature",         
          "creationDateTime" : "2023-02-21T12:14:38.8290009Z"
        }
}
```

I also tried:

```
                        q => q.Term(w => w.Field("eventType").Value("ParameterAlarmOutOfRange"))
```

mapping is:

```
 "eventType" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
```

Note that I am just assuming that my query syntax is correct. Problem is that there is simply no documentation about nest client and fluent notation.
It worked that way in version 7.x though...

update:
this is nest debuginformation for the query result:

```
Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST: /audit-trail-2023-02/object/_update_by_query?error_trace=true&conflicts=abort&refresh=true
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.2481553
# Request:
{"query":{"match":{"eventType":{"query":"ParameterAlarmOutOfRange"}}},"script":{"lang":"painless","inline":"ctx._source.parameterName = ctx._source.action.splitOnToken(':')[0]"}}
# Response:
{"took":4,"timed_out":false,"total":0,"updated":0,"deleted":0,"batches":0,"version_conflicts":0,"noops":0,"retries":{"bulk":0,"search":0},"throttled_millis":0,"requests_per_second":-1.0,"throttled_until_millis":0,"failures":[]}
```

also tried running raw query like:
var query = "{"match": {"eventType": "ParameterAlarmOutOfRange"}}";

```
            var result = client.UpdateByQuery<object>(
                u => u
                    .Index(index)
                    .Query(
                        q => q.Raw(query)
```

which again works fine on es 7 but does not return any results on es 5.
I noticed that mapping in es 7 is

```
  "eventType" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
```

but can this be an issue? keywords should also be working right?

Comment: What you get in `result.DebugInformation` when debug enabled?

Comment: wow If only I knew this before that debuginformation actually returns the raw query... see updated post for the result

Comment: First I would check if your term query is actually matching any docs in index with e.g. Kibana, if yes, would check if painless script is valid with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/5.5/painless-debugging.html

Comment: checked that search returns documents. same query ran by updatebyquery does not hit any docs though.

Comment: What is the index mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution:
problem was missing specification for .Type :

```
 var result = client.UpdateByQuery<dynamic>(
                        u => u
                            .Index(index)
                            .Type("audittrailentry")
...
```